# im unable to remove adjacent vaules from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

im trying to remove `adjacent` `duplicates` but instead of desired result **(3 results)** i'm getting only **2 results**

**my Expected Output:**

```
 [{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":0}},{"mw://diagnosis_HOME":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}}]
```

**here is what i have tried:**

```js
var arr = [{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":0}},{"mw://diagnosis_HOME":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}}];
var nArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;++i){
   var key1 = Object.keys(arr[i]).join('');
   var nLength = ((i + 1) > arr.length - 1 ) ? 0 : i + 1;
   var key2 = Object.keys(arr[nLength]).join('');
   if(key1 == key2) continue;
      nArr.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(nArr);
```

**from the above result you can see one more element is missing**

Comment: What you mean by remove adjacent values?

Comment: yes i meant that, no side by side value can be same, **in other word** `index 0` and `index 1` value is same then i want one among them

Comment: What happened if we have 3 same elements? `{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to use `filter`:

```js
var arr = [{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":0}},{"mw://diagnosis_HOME":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}}];

let lastKey;
const filtered = arr.filter((item) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  if (key === lastKey) return false;
  lastKey = key;
  return true;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for adjacent keys, you should just track the latest key, and not compare all of them.

```js
var arr = [{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":0}},{"mw://diagnosis_HOME":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}},{"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}}];

let result = [], prev_key = '', key;
for(let item of arr) {
  key = Object.keys(item).sort().join();
  if(key == prev_key) continue;
  prev_key = key;
  result.push(item);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = 
    [
      {"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":0}},
      {"mw://diagnosis_HOME":{"position":3}},
      {"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}},
      {"mw://HOME_BIN":{"position":3}}
    ];

var nArr = [];

arr.forEach((ar,index) => {
  if(index === arr.length - 1) {
    nArr.push(ar);
    return;
  }
  
  if(JSON.stringify(ar) !== JSON.stringify(arr[index+1])){
    nArr.push(ar);
  }
})

console.log(nArr);
```

You can use `JSON.stringify` to compare whole objects instead of using single key, for your scalability